# Regarding Physical Connectivity

Tags: ethernet, layer1

I have questions regarding the following designs in my test lab:

1.Ethernet port of one switch is connected to TenGig port of the Firewall.Why would anyone do this(connecting Ethernet and Tengigabit Ethernet)?

2.N5k E1/4 (LC type) connected to E1/4(LC type) with MMF as the media. The speed shown is 10Gb. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: On Cisco Nexus switches all Ethernet ports are named "Ethernet" regardless of port speed. So an Ethernet interface (with the right SPF) can operate at 10Gbps, yes.

Comment: The above is correct and should be made an answer.  On NXOS boxes all physical ports of any speed have the prefix "ethernet."  The only exception is management ports - which use "mgmt."